How to customize Form Validation error message for Password Confirmation Field
I am trying to customize Form Validation error message for Password Confirmation Field at User Creation Form.
My forms.py is like below.
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from .models import User

class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User        
        fields = ('first_name','last_name','email','date_of_birth', 'gender', 'user_type', 'phone', 'address','photo', 'password1', 'password2' )
        error_messages = {
            field: {
                'required': f"{field.replace('_', ' ').title()} is required."
            }
            for field in fields
        }
        
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field_name in self.fields:
            self.fields[field_name].error_messages.update(self.Meta.error_messages[field_name])

My views.py is like below.
class UserRegisterView( FormView ):
    template_name = 'register.html'
    form_class = CustomUserCreationForm
    
    redirect_authenticated_user = True
    success_url = reverse_lazy('dashboard')      

    def form_valid( self, form ):
        user = form.save()
        if user is not None:
            login( self.request, user )
        return super( UserRegisterView, self ).form_valid( form )
    
    def get( self, *args, **kwargs ):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('dashboard')
        return super( UserRegisterView, self ).get( *args, **kwargs )
    
    def form_invalid(self, form):
        return super(UserRegisterView, self).form_invalid(form)

My HTML code is like below.
<label class="form-label">PassWord Confirmation</label>
<input type="password" class="form-control" name="password2" />                                
{% if form.password2.errors %}
    <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ form.password2.errors }}</div>
{% endif %}

Now I am getting validation message Password2 is required.. But I would like to get validation message Password Confirmation is required..

I think there are no error in your views and html. SO,
the complete forms.py with the custom error message:
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from .models import User

class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User        
        fields = (
            'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'date_of_birth', 
            'gender', 'user_type', 'phone', 'address', 'photo', 
            'password1', 'password2'
        )
         # Override the error message for password2
        error_messages = {
            field: {
                'required': f"{field.replace('_', ' ').title()} is required."
            }
            for field in fields
        }
        error_messages['password2'] = {
            'required': "Password Confirmation is required."
        }
        
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field_name in self.fields:
            self.fields[field_name].error_messages.update(self.Meta.error_messages.get(field_name, {}))

explicitly setting the required error message for the password2 field in the error_messages dictionary, you can ensure that it displays Password Confirmation is required. when the field is not filled in.

You can override the defaults per each field for every possible validation error message form supports. In your case it would be:
error_messages = {
    'password2': {
        'required': "Password Confirmation is required.",
     },
}

If you want this to be dynamic, you can create a mapping where key would be your field and the value is another mapping with specific error messages per each validation case.
field_message__map = {
    'password2': {
        'required': "Password Confirmation is required.",
     },
    'password1': {
        'required': "Password is required.",
     },
}

And then you should use it in your Form definition
error_messages = {
    field: field_message__map[field] for field in fields
}

